# Solve the error java.io.StreamCorruptedException: Inconsistent vector internals

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-web, httpinvoker

I have a Spring webapp that uses HttpInvoker to connect to a Spring Boot service.
I have recently updated the service project to use Java 11 and at the same time updated it to Spring Boot starter 2.1.3.RELEASE.
The service project provides an interface jar with all the request and response objects and the Interface classes required when using HttpInvoker.

I ran in to this error but only on some of the service endpoints.
I have been trying, without success, to pinpoint what the difference is between the successful requests and the failing ones.

**Things I've tried to fix the issue**

- Both applications are running the same version of Java 11
- Updated the Spring webapp to use Spring 5.1.5.RELEASE, this is the same version that comes with the spring boot starter.

  - Updated both apps to use spring-web 5.1.5.RELEASE. This is where the remoting library comes from
  - Made sure I have **extends Serializable** on my response objects and have updated the serialVersionUID
  - Confirmed that I am using the correct version of the service interface in my webapp

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get this solved...I'm really scratching my head on this now

The main issue with this error is that the service receives the request from the webapp, processes the request and then responds. Somewhere in the remoting callback I get this error and my webapp responds with an exception however in the background the request has completed successfully.

Below is part of the stacktrace, I have left some out on purpose, let me know if you require more information.

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: Inconsistent vector internals
    at java.base/java.util.Vector.readObject(Vector.java:1191) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1160) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2216) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2087) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1594) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2355) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2205) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2087) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1594) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2355) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2205) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2087) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1594) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2355) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2249) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2087) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1594) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2355) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2249) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2087) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1594) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2355) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2249) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2087) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1594) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.doReadRemoteInvocationResult(AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:294) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.readRemoteInvocationResult(AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:245) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.SimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.doExecuteRequest(SimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:94) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.executeRequest(AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:140) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.executeRequest(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:206) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.executeRequest(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:188) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.invoke(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:154) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
Wrapped by: org.springframework.remoting.RemoteAccessException: Could not access HTTP invoker remote service at [http://localhost:8083/http-invoker/UniComAlerts]; nested exception is java.io.StreamCorruptedException: Inconsistent vector internals
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.convertHttpInvokerAccessException(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:231) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.invoke(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:157) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy101.updateAlertDeliverySettings(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88) ~[spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 2):

Check that serialized objerct and class that you read in are compile with same version of jdk.

Thanks